# Does this graph structure on a ring have any known uses, and/or is it studied anywhere?

Tags: graph-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Every ring $R$ becomes a graph as follows: given $a,b \in R$, an edge between $a$ and $b$ is, by definition, a non-zero idempotent of $R$ that when added to $a$ yields $b$. This is always a simple graph, and I rigged the definition so that two elements $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ share an edge iff $|a-b|=1$.

> **Question.** Does this graph structure on a ring have any known uses and/or is it studied anywhere?

I'm also perfectly happy to consider the obvious variant in which the non-zeroness condition is dropped; the result won't ever be a simple graph, but maybe that's okay.